# D3.js: xScale.bandwith is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm newbie with d3.js and I want to make a bar chart but I've got a problem when I try to draw the bars because I've got an error on line 62.

I don't know why it gives an error when inside the same function I make a consult and I've got the value which is returned by xScale.bandwith but not inside an attr.

Please, check this code:

[image: Edit single bar chart]

Why it happend? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just dictionary error

`scales.xScale.bandwidth()`
instead
`scales.xScale.bandwith()`

bandwi**d**th

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. In my case, it was due to a casing error. I was using `bandWidth` (with a capital 'W'). However, the method name is `bandwidth` (all lower case).

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `bandwith` as a function while it is a property.

Correct the line 62 to :

```js
.attr("width", scales.xScale.bandwith)
```

Comment: Ok, the error has gone!!! But, why before I've got the value of bandwith with this instrucction: console.log("x bandwith2: " + scales.xScale.bandwidth())?

Comment: bandwidth is a function in scales of d3

Comment: This just *happens* to work because d3.js will accept either a value or a function for the second argument. The explanation is incorrect, though; as [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639629/d3-js-xscale-bandwith-is-not-a-function#comment127140270_60639759), `bandwidth` *is* actually a function.